# Difference between vegetable shortening and vegetable ghee?

Tags: baking, substitutions

What is difference between vegetable shortening and vegetable ghee? Can we use vegetable ghee as its substitute?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really any difference between the two apart from the colour. Sometimes ghee contains a few extra flavourings to make the taste more distinctive. However, I don't think there's much of a difference.